# Merge tags 'startup' and 'boot'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

What should the difference be between the two? Both deal with the startup/boot process of the device, and related issues. From the questions tagged such I cannot tell why they shouldn't use the other tag instead. Hence my request:

- Merge [boot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot) (x9) into [startup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/startup) (x9) or vice-versa (in that case, make sure the tag wiki of `startup` is not lost)
- Make the "empty one" a synonym to the merge target

Comment: I tend to agree there's some redundancy, but I'm also inclined to think that `startup` is now kind of an obsolete/not useful tag. It may be best to simply retag questions with `startup` to either `boot` or `auto-start` as appropriate, then let it die off or something. My 2 cents, anyway.

Comment: I see x65 and x19, not x9 and x9.  Agreed with eldarerathis as well.  `device-startup` could be a synonym for `boot`.  Also, get more rep so I don't have to blindly spam Approve on your tag wikis anymore :P

Comment: @MatthewRead Oh, that brings me to another issue to keep in mind when counting: I was on the 'faq' tab, which I always counted as a "sorting" rather than a "restricting" algorithm. Switching to 'Newest' indeed shows more #/

Comment: @eldarerathis You've made your point, and I can agree to it :) However, this might make the 'startup' tag re-appearing from time to time -- hence I still keep up my "request" making it a synonym to 'boot' after cleanup. I will see to it that I go over all 'startup' question and re-tag as suggested, if the others agree?

Comment: I guess I'm just not sure if it would be a better synonym for `auto-start` or something along those lines (but yeah, it's probably not a bad idea to synonymize it with *something* so people won't use it). I could probably go either way.

Comment: I'd say make it a synonym to `boot`. Why? There is the `shutdown` tag as well, which then would correspond (see e.g. [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35341/)).

Comment: Finished: Re-tagged all questions but two (which I could not edit as they were merged).